# Snapping two objects at runtime at specific points on the object

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine

I have many game objects with line renderers attached to it . They are roughly in the shape of rectangles . How do I go about snapping these rectangle on the edges when these objects are dragged and bought close to each other ?

I have referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436224/how-to-snap-two-objects-in-runtime-in-unity) . But it doesn't explain how to snap at specific positions.

Here is a sample image of the objects I want to latch.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align "tracks" or modular objects in Unity ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122220/how-to-align-tracks-or-modular-objects-in-unity)

Comment: @Lotan how do I place snapping points at runtime via script (I have the coordinates) as mentioned in the link you have commented , should I create empty game objects?

Comment: @Kitwadr yes, I think it's the best approach ^^

Comment: @Lotan what do you suggest the game object is ? A combination of a collider and a rigid body?

Comment: that depends completly of your app-behaviour, but I'll suggest that the snap points do not have rigidbody, cause you don't really need it. You can play also with compound colliders, but maybe results in a mess ^^

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to do this task. Simply you can calculate the position of the second shape and when it's becoming closer to first with x or y axis just set their start position to first shape end position. The second way is just adding 2D colliders near the first object and simply when it triggers, move position. I will strongly recommend the first way.

Comment: There is nothing called start position and end position I just have a bunch of coordinates representing each polygon